# Display buttons at fix position

Tags: html, css, angular, bootstrap-4, angular8

I am using grid in my angular html form. Grid is as follows:

```
 .grid {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
        grid-gap: 2%;
        grid-auto-rows: 90%;
    }
```

This grid will make two rectangles in parallel. Now I have some divs which will display data  on these rectangles and each of these has one button at bottom. But when one or the other div don't have data to display , my buttons move up the grid. I want these buttons to be at bottom of grid at fix positions and don't move up when div above buttons don't display data.How can I do that.

Answer (score 1):

To keep the button at the bottom when there is no data to display, you should set the `display` attribute of the element where the button is inserted to `flex` and the `margin-top` of the button to `auto`.

You also have to remove `grid-auto-rows: 90%;` of the `.grid` class or at least set it to auto. This is causing your grid not to grow properly with the content.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-auto-rows#Values

**HTML:**

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="cell">
    <div>
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua.</p>
    </div>
    <button class="button">My Button 1</button>
  </div>
  <div class="cell">
    <button class="button">My Button 2</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```css
.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 2%;
  grid-auto-rows: auto;
}

.cell {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.button {
  margin-top: auto;
  height: 40px;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 200px;
}
```

`.cell` is the element where the button and content are inserted.
See here a working example: https://codepen.io/bosoria/pen/MWgdVej